# Read excel sheet without using POI api

Tags: struts

I am having an urgent requirement.
 Reading data from excel sheet. 
Is there any procedure to read data from excel sheet without using apache poi api. i have to use only struts.

Thanking you,
Vipul Kumar.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean you "only have to use Struts"? If that means you cannot use any other library (and I hope it doesn't), you only have one way: implement an Excel parser yourself.

I strongly advise you against it, though. Why would you want to reinvent the wheel?

If not, then there are a couple of alternatives to help you:

1. Apache POI
2. JExcelApi