# How to read byte stream as an Excel sheet without using POI in Java?

Tags: java

I have a Servlet which accepts uploaded Excel file from the user.

I convert that file into byte stream and store onto the DB. Now I want to read the same byte stream as an Excel file. But this is to achieved without creating a temporary Excel file and also without using any third party library.

How can I do that?

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250024/how-to-obtain-sheet-names-from-xls-files-without-loading-the-whole-file-in-pytho), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611816/read-excel-sheet-without-using-poi-api) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21085977/how-to-read-an-excel-multiple-sheet-to-store-the-content-of-excel-sheet-into-dat). But did not help.

Comment: To read the Excel file format without third-party libraries would mean implementing your own (first-part) Excel file format library. I don't know the scope of your project, but that's almost certainly too big of a task for that project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read excel sheet without using POI api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611816/read-excel-sheet-without-using-poi-api)

Comment: While you already link to that question and say it "did not help", it still is the correct answer: you can't do it this way, unless you write everything from scratch (which you really don't want to do).

Comment: I have restrictions on using third party APIs

Comment: that still doesn't change the correctness of that answer. Just because you don't like the answer doesn't make it wrong.